# Opening cached file in android

Tags: java, android, java-io, android-file

I'd like to open a file that I written copied to my *cacheDir* (e.g audio file, or image) with an intent, but it seems like other apps don't have the permission to this directory. It's quite reasonable (my logic tells me that only root and the app have the access to this folder), but is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's quite obvious my friend, use activity.getExternalCacheDir() to obtain a cache dir on your SD card. Just don't forget to set the permissions.